# How to send a message to a MQ Cluster with .Net?

Tags: .net, ibm-mq

I need to send a message to a MQ Cluster using .Net. How do I do it?

```
        MQEnvironment.Hostname = "10.1.1.22";
        MQEnvironment.Port = 1455;
        MQEnvironment.Channel = "SOMECHANNEL";
        MQEnvironment.ConnectionName = "10.1.1.22(1432)";
        MQQueueManager qm =new MQQueueManager("SOMEQM");

            var openOptions = MQC.MQOO_INPUT_AS_Q_DEF| MQC.MQOO_OUTPUT;
            var queue = qm.AccessQueue("MYREQUESTQUEUE", openOptions);
```

Currently this is failing on the last line. What are the **proper options** to send when opening a connection to a cluster queue?

Answer (score 1):

Couple of points:

1) A cluster queue may not be hosted on the queue manager to which your application is connected to.

2) Messages can be put to a cluster queue that is not hosted on the queue manager your application is connected. But to `GET` messages, queue `must` be hosted on the queue manager to which your application is connected to.

Your application is using `MQC.MQOO_INPUT_AS_Q_DEF` option, meaning you are trying to GET messages from a queue but the that queue is not present on the queue manager your application is connected to. Hence exception is being thrown. You need to remove `MQC.MQOO_INPUT_AS_Q_DEF` option and just use `MQC.MQOO_OUTPUT` to send/put messages to cluster queue.